# How can i compiking sn extension with phpcpp using mac osx yosemite

Tags: c++, php-cpp

I am creating my first extension but i have found this error compiling "ld library not found for -lphpcpp" how can i solve it? I am using mac osx yosemite

Comment: You need to install phpcpp http://www.php-cpp.com/documentation/install, the compiler cannot find the library

Comment: is installed the phpcpp but when i build the extension i've this error:sudo make
g++ -shared -undefined dynamic_lookup -o yourextension.so main.o -lphpcpp
ld: library not found for -lphpcpp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [yourextension.so] Error 1

Comment: you need to specify the library path with -L